# Calling a REST Webservice from Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I am trying to call a REST webservice from an Android app that I am running on an emulator. I can call the service from my browser with

```
http://localhost:39064/AndroidServiceImpl.svc/submitexcerpt?excerpt=...and+the+pirate+fell+off+the+boat
```

I can call the service from my emulator with

```
http://10.0.2.2:39064/AndroidServiceImpl.svc/submitexcerpt?excerpt=...and+the+pirate+fell+off+the+boat
```

But when I run this code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response1;
response1 = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:39064/AndroidServiceImpl.svc/submitexcerpt?excerpt=testingthisout"));
```

I get a *connection refused* exception. I have added the  `<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></user-permission>` to my Manifest file, and set the ThreadPolicy to LAX but still no luck. Any Suggestions?

Comment: The Source Not Found tab no longer comes up because I am catching it in a general Exception, I wasn't before and that caused it to come up.  I am now getting a connection refused exception that i am looking into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer rather than putting 
`<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></user-permission>` 
I needed 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` 
So just some bullet points on calling a webservice:
*add to Manifest.xml file
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>`
*use 10.0.2.2 rather than localhost for a locally consumed service
*Set the Thread Policy to lax(not recommended for production) or use AsyncTask
`ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);`

Comment: Lizzard, you might want to click the checkmark to answer your own question.  Free rep!

Answer (score 0):

Verify that `10.0.2.2` is your machine address(run ifconfig to verify it ), also  this is a common problem, when there is no internet on the emulator so make sure your emulator is connected.

Comment: I have verified this with the url http://10.0.2.2:39064/AndroidServiceImpl.svc/submitexcerpt?excerpt=...and+the+pirate+fell+off+the+boat I can access the webservice via the web browser on the emulator

Comment: I have also added the ThreadPolicy.LAX to turn the strict mode off to prevent the NetworkOnMainthreadexception